Godot и SQL, ошибка при редактировании таблицы
У меня возникли трудности при взаимодействии со sql таблицей в Godot.
Вот код, с помощью которого подключаюсь к таблице
func _ready():
    db = SQLite.new()
    db.path = data_path
    db.open_db()
    db.query("select * from books")

С чтение таблицы трудностей нет, все находится, все читается, есть проблема с изменением данных в таблице. Даже при использовании какого-нибудь простого запроса вроде
db.query("UPDATE books SET ReadPages = 100 WHERE ID = 1")

я получаю ошибку Invalid get index '0'(on base 'Array') в той части кода, которая вообще никак не связана с изменениями, и без изменений в таблице работает прекрасно. Причем изменения в таблицу вносятся и только после этого появляется ошибка.
Есть подозрение, что я где-то не обновляю подключаемую таблицу, но так ли это? И если так, то как это можно грамотно сделать?

Приведите [mcve], после попытки составить рабочий код из показываемых вами кусочков в Godot 4.2 у меня всё успешно работает
